Canonical question for guidance on letters of recommendation?
I feel like there are quite a lot of questions concerning letters of recommendation recently, often always the lines of:

Should I rather ask person A with background X and interaction history Y or rather person B with background Z that I have not interacted with extensively?

other issues include:

number of letters
occasion specific guidance for letterr
regional specific issues for LORs

I wonder if a canonical question that provides a general guidline on recommendation letters would make sense? Many of these questions are kind of the same, but differ a bit because of personal circumstances, put are often general enough to not be closed for depending too much on personal factors. Yet there is a lot of repetition, and many suggestions overlap.

Still thinking about it, but this seems like it might be a good idea. If others agree, are you volunteering to draft such a question / answer, or would we need to find a volunteer? I think we’ve had a couple canonical questions now that were green lit but never made it to the writing stage due to a lack of volunteers. (In fact, in the last 30 months, there have only been 2 canonical questions, and I wrote both of them.)

@cag51 I can try to draft something from existinig answers, but this really is not my area of expertise - I never had to get a letter of recommendation (in Germany they are less important anyway). But as I said, I can start something from existing answers or maybe even better try to find a question that is general enough for it to be made into the canonical question.

@cag51 Took a stab at at it. Might go dig up more links later.

We receive many questions about how to select recommenders, especially
because there is usually a limit on the number of letters.
For differences between countries, see this question,
but in general,  Americans tend to write very effusive letters compared to
Europeans, which can sometime cause confusion when cultures clash.
But this post is about how to select letter-writers.
There are a few dimensions to consider, and your potential letter-writers
will vary on all of them. One of our goals with this canonical question is to
avoid every possible permutation of new/old professor, knows me well/doesn't,
etc.
Primary factors

Letters should be specific to you and work you did. A letter-writer who
knows you well is better than one who you only took a class from, even if
the latter publishes more. A generic letter is bad.

Letter-writers should be able to talk about your suitability for the grad program at hand. If you're applying to a PhD program, a person with a
PhD is better than someone else (e.g., your boss, a medical doctor).

Likewise, a letter is more likely to be successful if the program has
previously had successful applicants recommended by your writer.


It's best if your letter-writer succeeded in the kind of program you're applying
to. A PhD student's letter may not be suitable for PhD admission, but may be an appropriate choice for a post-bacc program or scholarship, etc.,
if they know you well.

Seniority is a consideration. More experienced scholars will be able to
offer perspecives from their long career, especially if they have a history
of making good recommendations and satisfy the conditions above. That said, you do not need to ask the
Nobel laureate down the hall instead of a mentor who has worked with
you for a while.


Asking instructors or non-academics
The best letter-writers are those who have supervised you as an independent  scholar.
Someone you have only taken a class from is a last resort; if you do
ask you should have done very well in their class, preferably upper-division.
Finally, for academic programs, you should try to get all academic
letter-writers. Sometimes, this isn't possible, and someone who knows your
recent work (i.e., a boss) is better than a professor you took a class with
4+ years ago.
Summary
If you're applying to graduate school, hopefully you have at least one
primary mentor who can help you select your other letter-writers.
But to summarize, your letter-writers should know you well and be able to predict that you will be successful.
Finally, give them a lot of heads-up! A month before the due date is a common
minimum timeframe.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12959/who-should-write-a-recommendation-letter?rq=1 Here is a question that might yield some more relevant info

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/96786/reference-letter-personal-vs-prestigious

Your #4 isn't so one sided. In a fast changing field, we old buzzards may not be as up to date on what is needed as the young hawks. Number 3 and 4 might not align.

@Buffy Feel free to edit, although I said "a consideration."

@AzorAhai-him-: I think we're good to go; feel free to post it. People can continue to edit / add once it's live as CW.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47373/how-do-i-effectively-solicit-a-strong-letter-of-recommendation-from-a-professor/47374#47374 covers much of this

It was actually formed as one.

Scott's answer is excellent. Perhaps we could migrate some of the content from this answer into the "ask the appropriate people" section and then make that a canonical question. Though, canonical questions are usually community wiki.

I think this is a good idea.
I recommend that the title / scope be: "Who should I ask to write a letter of recommendation?" And then the canonical answer should cover:

Who to choose among multiple options (there are many different permutations here, so for this to be a useful dupe target, we should explicitly cover many different classes of potential recommenders -- e.g., all possible academic ranks, and all possible types of relationships with the recommendee).
What to do if you can't find or think of a recommender
What a good or weak letter looks like (since this will influence the above choice), as well as any known differences between cultures or fields
Whether "extra" letters are helpful


Would also include regional differences

What is the process for actually turning the suggested answer into a canonical question? Since posting this, there have been several more questions about this exact topic and we have been linking this meta question, but it would be great to get this to the main site

I agree. I'm not sure why Azor didn't make a post on the main site with the above text. And @Scott's answer is also excellent, so maybe we should merge with that rather than making a new one -- though I'm not sure if Scott wants his post to made CW. Either way, the next step is for there to be a CW post on the main site along the lines of what was discussed here, and a mod can add the "canonical" tag to that.
